# Wave equation with 'spring' integral boundary condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, wave-equation

I am really stuck with this small toy problem.

I am trying to solve a wave equation on unit interval $x \in [0,1]$ with a specific boundary condition which I can't see how to tackle. The problem is:

Find $(u, P)$ subject to 
$$ u_t + P_x = F(x,t), \\ P_t + u_x = 0. $$

here $F(x,t) = x \cdot U(t)$ is a known force term. For simplicity let's say for now the initial conditions are zero. The boundary conditions are:

$$u(x=1, t) = 0, \\ \frac{P(x=0, t)}{m} = V_{tt} + \omega^2 V, \quad and \\ u(x=0, t) = V_t, \\ V(t=0) = V_0$$

The boundary condition at $x=0$ is a way to model a spring connected to the main domain. $V$ is the spring displacement and is only a function of time $t$. $\omega$ and $m$ are just some constants.

My main problem is that I get a second order boundary condition at $x=0$ (namely $-u_{xx} + \omega^2 u = u_x/m$), and I don't know whether this problem is solvable in general.

Alternatively, I can rewrite the bc as:

$$
\omega^2 \int_0^t u(x=0,\tau) d\tau = \frac{P(x=0,t)}{m} + P_x(x=0,t)
$$

Ideally, I would like to find an analytical solution to this.

Thank you!